# How to detect when mouse (pointer) is over text in JList?

Tags: java, swing, popup, row, jlist

I am using a JList to display elements. I want to provide a popup menu to interact with the specific elements under the mouse. I am using a MouseInputListener, isPopupTrigger(), locationToIndex(), getCellBounds(), etc. I haven't posted code for this as it's not the point, just background for the question. What I ultimately want to do is only post the popup menu when the correct (platform- and UI-dependent) action occurs **over the text in the JList cell** - not just anywhere in the row. My JList is in a ScrollPane which is in a SplitPane. The width of the JList cells can be much larger than the text. If the user is able to post the popup by clicking far to the right of the text in the row when the SplitPane is much larger than the extent of the text, it will be unclear just which row is being operated on. I don't want to select the row that the user would be interacting with using the popup menu because selection has a different meaning in this context. So the basic question is: how can I determine if the mouse location when the popup trigger occurs is actually over the text in the row, rather than just in the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JList's cell renderer returns JLabels (which it will by default, or if you have set the renderer to a DefaultListCellRenderer), you can use [SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#layoutCompoundLabel-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.FontMetrics-java.lang.String-javax.swing.Icon-int-int-int-int-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-int-) to determine the bounds of the text:

```
static <E> boolean isOverText(Point location,
                              JList<E> list) {

    int index = list.locationToIndex(location);
    if (index < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    E value = list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
    ListCellRenderer<? super E> renderer = list.getCellRenderer();
    Component c = renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
        list.isSelectedIndex(index),
        list.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex() == index);

    if (c instanceof JLabel) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) c;

        Icon icon = null;
        if (!label.isEnabled()) {
            icon = label.getDisabledIcon();
        }
        if (icon == null) {
            icon = label.getIcon();
        }

        Rectangle listItemBounds =
            SwingUtilities.calculateInnerArea(label, null);
        Rectangle cellBounds = list.getCellBounds(index, index);
        listItemBounds.translate(cellBounds.x, cellBounds.y);
        listItemBounds.width = cellBounds.width;
        listItemBounds.height = cellBounds.height;

        Rectangle textBounds = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle iconBounds = new Rectangle();

        SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(label,
            label.getFontMetrics(label.getFont()),
            label.getText(),
            icon,
            label.getVerticalAlignment(),
            label.getHorizontalAlignment(),
            label.getVerticalTextPosition(),
            label.getHorizontalTextPosition(),
            listItemBounds,
            iconBounds,
            textBounds,
            label.getIconTextGap());

        return textBounds.contains(location);
    }
```

Comment: +1 for what looks like complete approach. Me being lazy would have assumed the list is only rendering text which would be left justified so I would only have used the preferred size (width) of the renderer to check if the mouse is over the text. But I guess different LAF's could decide to center/right justify the text.